# A question about Cayley–Hamilton theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

In wikipedia "In linear algebra, the Cayley–Hamilton theorem (named after the mathematicians Arthur Cayley and William Rowan Hamilton) states that every square matrix over a commutative ring (such as the real or complex field) satisfies its own characteristic equation."
$\iff$ If $A$ is an $n\times n$ martix and $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity martix and $\text{let}$ $f(\lambda)=\text{det}(\lambda I_n-A)$ then we get $f(A)=0$.

In my book and wiki both use a order polynomial expression to prove it.

The question is: Why can't we just let $\lambda=A $ $\Rightarrow$ $\lambda I_n=AI_n=A$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(A)=\text{det}(A-A)=0$

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: because $\lambda$ is a number? and you are substituting a matrix where a number is?

Comment: yes!Lost is right!also \lambda I_n=AI_n=A
is not correct .if x_\lambda be eigen value correspond with \lmbda then you will have \lambda I_n x_\lambda=Ax_\lambda

Comment: See this [Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley-Hamilton_theorem#A_bogus_.22proof.22:_p.28A.29_.3D_det.28AIn.C2.A0.E2.88.92.C2.A0A.29_.3D_det.28A.C2.A0.E2.88.92.C2.A0A.29_.3D_0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&a_{1,3}&\ldots& a_{1,n-2}& a_{1,n-1}& a_{1,n}\\ 
a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&a_{2,3}&\ldots& a_{2,n-2}& a_{2,n-1}& a_{2,n}\\
a_{3,1}&a_{3,2}&a_{3,3}&\ldots& a_{3,n-2}& a_{3,n-1}& a_{3,n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots\\
a_{n-2,1}&a_{n-2,2}&a_{n-2,3}&\ldots& a_{n-2,n-2}& a_{n-2,n-1}& a_{n-2,n}\\
a_{n-1,1}&a_{n-1,2}&a_{n-1,3}&\ldots& a_{n-1,n-2}& a_{n-1,n-1}& a_{n-1,n}\\
a_{n,1}&a_{n,2}&a_{n,3}&\ldots& a_{n,n-2}& a_{n,n-1}& a_{n,n}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then 
 $$
\lambda I-A=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda -a_{1,1}&-a_{1,2}&-a_{1,3}&\ldots& -a_{1,n}& -a_{1,n-1}& -a_{1,n}\\ 
-a_{2,1}&\lambda -a_{2,2}&-a_{2,3}&\ldots& -a_{2,n-2}& -a_{2,n-1}& -a_{2,n}\\
-a_{3,1}&-a_{3,2}&\lambda -a_{3,3}&\ldots& -a_{3,n-2}& -a_{3,n-1}& -a_{3,n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots\\
-a_{n-2,1}&-a_{n-2,2}&-a_{n-2,3}&\ldots&\lambda -a_{n-2,n-2}& -a_{n-2,n-1}& -a_{n-2,n}\\
-a_{n-1,1}&-a_{n-1,2}&-a_{n-1,3}&\ldots& -a_{n-1,n-2}&\lambda -a_{n-1,n-1}& -a_{n-1,n}\\
-a_{n,1}&-a_{n,2}&-a_{n,3}&\ldots& -a_{n,n-2}& -a_{n,n-1}&\lambda -a_{n,n}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\Longrightarrow\\
0=A I-A=\begin{pmatrix}
A -a_{1,1}&-a_{1,2}&-a_{1,3}&\ldots& -a_{1,n}& -a_{1,n-1}& -a_{1,n}\\ 
-a_{2,1}&A -a_{2,2}&-a_{2,3}&\ldots& -a_{2,n-2}& -a_{2,n-1}& -a_{2,n}\\
-a_{3,1}&-a_{3,2}&A -a_{3,3}&\ldots& -a_{3,n-2}& -a_{3,n-1}& -a_{3,n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots\\
-a_{n-2,1}&-a_{n-2,2}&-a_{n-2,3}&\ldots&A -a_{n-2,n-2}& -a_{n-2,n-1}& -a_{n-2,n}\\
-a_{n-1,1}&-a_{n-1,2}&-a_{n-1,3}&\ldots& -a_{n-1,n-2}&A -a_{n-1,n-1}& -a_{n-1,n}\\
-a_{n,1}&-a_{n,2}&-a_{n,3}&\ldots& -a_{n,n-2}& -a_{n,n-1}&A -a_{n,n}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\\
???
$$

Comment: What a big mistake i have taken.......Thankyou